# convert array to object in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, arraylist

I am using an API that returns value like this:

`print APIresultValue`

it returns like this

```
(MyResult){
   Name = Mike
   LastName = Vin
   Middlle= Thu
 }
```

is it possible that I can convert it into object to be exact return like this:

```
(ArrayOfMyResult){
MyResults[] = 
(MyResult){
   Name = Mike
   LastName = Vin
   Middlle= Thu
 }
}
```

during in the loop I don't want to get the value by `item[0]` but instead `item['Name']`

for now when I loop and get the value it

`for item in APIresultValue:
  print item[0] # to get the value of Name`

Is it possible that I can get the value by converting it to object? like

`for item in APIresultValue:
  print item['Name'] # to get the value of Name`

is it possible?

Comment: is that python code?

Comment: a value that returns from python code `print` in given value, I just want to convert it into object using python

Comment: What returns this? Its the second time I've seen this format today.

Comment: It may already be in an object form. What you're displaying is probably the output from the `__str__` or `__repr__` method of that class. in your loop try `print item.__dict__`. This will show you the properties of the object.